# Pass whole script as argument to powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, command-line, vbscript, arguments

I once found a script to easily change my Wallpaper if I use multiple ones.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("^ ")
WshShell.SendKeys("+{F10}")
WshShell.SendKeys("n")
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

However I need a separate link that calls the script.
Now I wonder if I can pass these multiple lines of code as parameter to powershell.exe directly.

I did read that I can allign multiple lines using `;` and tried building the one-liner, however it doesn't run...or rather it does run, there is no feedback, nothing changes. If I paste the command line into a running powershell instance it just exits.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command "set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject('WScript.Shell'); WshShell.SendKeys('^ '); WshShell.SendKeys('+{F10}'); WshShell.SendKeys('n'); WshShell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')"
```

I basically just concatenated them and replaced the double quotes with single quotes to escape the special characters, so why does it not work as the separate script?

Comment: If you want to execute a script from the powershell.exe command line, use the `-File` parameter. (You must specify `-File` last on the powershell.exe command line.)

Comment: That is vbscript.. not powershell

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman to the comment already posted, which refers to the powershell.exe command line (nothing more, nothing less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
$WSH = New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell'
$WSH.SendKeys('^ ')
$WSH.SendKeys('+{F10}')
$WSH.SendKeys('n')
$WSH.SendKeys('{ENTER}')
```

Save this as a script (`Filename.ps1`), and call it from a `.bat` or `.cmd` file:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "path\filename.ps1"
```

Alternatively, as a one-liner in a command file:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "$WSH = New-Object -ComObject 'WScript.Shell';$WSH.SendKeys('\^ ');$WSH.SendKeys('+{F10}');$WSH.SendKeys('n');$WSH.SendKeys('{ENTER}')"
```

Comment: Thank you, that one-liner is exactly what I searched for!